# Unity Accessing PlayOneShot from different script throws object reference error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to play AudioClips from an Array of AudioClips, and I tried to make it work with AudioSource.PlayOneShot but for whatever reason I'm getting the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error at the line where the PlayOneShot is, when I try to access it from a different script. 
So what I did, I created an empty game object and I attached an AudioSource component to it and the AudioControler script. The script looks like this:

```
public AudioClip[] clips;
AudioSource audioSource;
private void Start(){
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
  }
public void PlaySound(){
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clips[0], 1);
  }
```

Then I attached some audio clips to the "clips" array in the editor, and I call the PlaySound() method from the other script and it gives me the error. Any idea what I did wrong here?

Comment: can we see in the editor where you have attached the clips?

Comment: @Jake yes, I updated the question.

Comment: Did you try a breakpoint to look at the values? Is the `array[0]` or the `AudioSource` null?

Comment: @Jake yes, the array at index 0 is returning the name of the clip, and the audioSource returns the name of the object it is attached to (on start).. The error still prevails. (tho, for some reason if I try to debug the PlaySound() method it throws the same error when I want to access the clips[0] with debug.log)

Comment: @Jake it looks like the accessing from the other script is the problem. I ran PlaySound method on the start of this script and it works. But if I try to call the PlaySound method from other script it throws the error. I'm accessing this method in the second script by: ObjectSounds os = new ObjectSounds(); and then os.PlaySound();

Comment: Stupid question but did you remember to disable your original object when creating this test one?

Comment: @Jake What do you mean by that? I should be able to run the PlaySound() method from the other script, I just can't see where is the catch. If I run the method in his script it works. I can access it from the other script, but getting the error when I actually trigger it..

Comment: What is ObjectSounds? does it inherit from monobehavior?

Comment: @Jake yes, it inherits from MonoBehaviour, and it is the class of the script which is attached to the game-object that should manage the soundclips.

Comment: Okay, I'm surprised your development environment did't warn you, you really shouldn't instantiate `monobehavior` objects with `new` at all, but especially in this case because how will the instantiated object have your list of clips in it? Why are you constructing it at runtime, does it need to be that way?

Comment: @Jake I'm really surprised also, and I didn't knew that it is a bad practice to instantiate monos with new..I never had an issue like this before. lol It doesn't need to construct at runtime, but I didn't had a better idea and this one looked like an easy solution at first...What should be the best practice for this situation?

Comment: There is a good answer [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/653904/you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-using-the-2.html) explaining why `new` is bad. you could you create your object in the editor and drag a reference to it on the object where it needs to be called, alternatively you can look into making an audiomanager [singleton class](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern), or a [good tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OT43pvUyfY)

Comment: @Jake I appreciate your help! Thank you! I will now dive into this.

Comment: No problem, best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was** - Accessing the monobehaviour script from another script, I tied to instantiate it with `new` and that was a really bad Idea! Don't try to instantiate Scripts that inherits from `MonoBehaviour` with `new`!!! This helped me to understand: [MonoBehaviour](https://answers.unity.com/questions/653904/you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-using-the-2.html)

**The solution that I used to solve the problem** - I created a Singleton Class and accessed the method I wanted through that. It look like the simplest solution to this problem. Look at: [Singleton](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern)

Other helpful topics: [Singleton](https://answers.unity.com/questions/891380/unity-c-singleton.html)

I hope that nobody will have this problem but if you do, I hope that my mistake can help you at least.

Answer (score 0):

public void PlaySound(){
if(audioSource != null)
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clips[0], 1);

}